# is StringProperty with choices optimized for enum values?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

in Google App Engine, python ndb datastore, I need to save an enum field. I see that the StringProperty has the `choices` option, where I could list the enum values.

However, it looks like on the actual datastore they are saved as regular strings, which is not optimal in size I assume. Is this the right approach to do this?

Should I save it as integer and use constants (ugly!!), or simply leave it like this since it won't make a huge difference anyway?

Comment: Choices only does validation on the valid set of strings.  So it doesn't actually add any real value.  Just store it as a StringProperty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the python source code for the StringProperty class, the choices value passed in is only used in the Property superclass for validation: http://pastebin.com/N6s0TaXU

Either way the configuration of choices is hard coded: either as a StringProperty param or in a dict that maps the choices to enum values.

The cost of writing/maintaining that extra functionality to deal with the enum is probably not worth the db space savings of storing an enum vs a string.

Just store the choices in the StringProperty.